# Making the last element occupy the remaining space

Tags: css, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul style="width: 100%; height: 33px;">
    <li style="height: 33px; width: 34px;">
        <div>TEST</div>
    </li>
    <li style="height: 33px; width: 34px;">
        <div>TEST</div>
    </li>
    <li style="height: 33px; width: 34px;">
        <div>TEST</div>
    </li>
    <li style="height: 33px;">
        <div>LAST</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
ul {
   list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 4px; 
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

And I would like the last element to occupy the remaining place, so it's aligned in the right of the page.

How to do so?

Thank you

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PKw9k/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the float.  You can also remove the width.

```
li:last-child { float: none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PKw9k/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using `overflow: hidden` on the last element and removing float

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/PKw9k/2/

Comment: it works without the `overflow:hidden`, the `float:none` does it. Thanks.